# How to Pass Type dynamically to System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I would like to create a procedure that returns everything dynamically so that I don't have to develop a switch on string to find the correct type. I tried to get a type from a string:

```
Type myDynamicType = Type.GetType("myDynamicType");
var objects = dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<myDynamicType>($"SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE Id > 0").ToList();
```

This code doesn't work because return this error:

> Error CS0118  'myDynamicType' is a variable but is used like a type

Comment: Why would you have a switch?  Just use a `Dictionary<string, Type>`.

Comment: yes, dictionary is better, but I don't want dictionary too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you cannot have a `List<typeof(int)>` if you want a `List<int>`.

But you are lucky, there is a non-generic overload for this.

```
 var objects = dataContext.Database.SqlQuery(myDynamicType, $"SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE 
     WHERE Id > 0").ToList()
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it works. Now I feel me so stupid. :( 
I found some problem with qualified name but I solved reading this:
typeof(ApiWarehouse).AssemblyQualifiedName;
and there isn't ToList I must use async method
.ToListAsync().Result;

Thank you <= sorry this is out of rules of stackoverflow, but thanks.